# json string downloaded with mising values c# webclient

Tags: missing-data

I'm conding a rent car asp.net mvc application and I have a strange problem.

I used the skyscanner api to get the available cars list but the json string downloaded is always missing the attribute cars or there is cars that exist and are available.

```
 string datacar = "";
        String ch = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/carhire/liveprices/v2/UK/eur/fr/" + ids + "/" + ide + "/" + dstart + "T" + tstart + "/" + dend + "T" + tend + "/30?apiKey=dh219253907683824017371755201462&userip=127.0.0.1";
        Uri url = new Uri(ch);
        // Uri url2 = new Uri("http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/carhire/liveprices/v2/UK/eur/fr/27539733/27539733/2016-09-10T17:45/2016-09-17T17:45/30?apiKey=dh219253907683824017371755201462&userip=127.0.0.1");
        CarModel model = new CarModel();
        // for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
        // {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "application/json");
            datacar = wc.DownloadString(url);
            //datacar = wc.DownloadString(url2);
            model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarModel>(datacar);
        }
```

and here it is the carModel defintion

```
namespace carrent.Models
{

public class SubmittedQuery
{
    public string market { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string locale { get; set; }
    public string pickup_place { get; set; }
    public string dropoff_place { get; set; }
    public string pickup_date_time { get; set; }
    public string drop_off_date_time { get; set; }
    public string driver_age { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class CarClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int sort_order { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class DebugItem
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class CarModel
{
    public SubmittedQuery submitted_query { get; set; }
    public List<object> cars { get; set; }
    public List<object> websites { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public List<CarClass> car_classes { get; set; }
    public List<DebugItem> debug_items { get; set; }
}
}
```

Ps: the strange thing in this problem is when I initialize an url (the url2) the code run perfectly

please guys help me to get the solution and thanks